# Android - when exiting a WebView, the audio still keeps playing

Tags: android, android-webview

I have this code which works and the only problem with it is that if I leave the WebView and even close the app, and even press power on the phone, the audio from the podcasts keeps playing.

Would anyone know how to stop that?

Here is the code:

```
public class PodcastsActivity extends BaseActivity //implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener 
{    
    WebView webview = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.podcasts);


        webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setInitialScale(1);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });




        //webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //webSettings.getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture();
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        setContentView(webview);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.stitcher.com/podcast/entrepreneuronfirecom/entrepreneur-on-fire-tim-ferriss-other-incredible-entrepreneurs");           

    }

//  public void onBackPressed ( )
//  {
//      Class.forName("com.***.HTML5WebView").getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null).
//      invoke(html5WebView, (Object[]) null);
//  }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) 
        {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }       

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
       super.onStop();
       // your code

       webview.clearView();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but just try to clear the cache on exit. In `onPause()`: `mWebView.clearCache(true); mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);`

Comment: Trying it now - thank you. Will report back with what happens in a few minutes :)

Comment: It actually says that super.onPageFinished(view, url);  is undefined for the type Activity. Would you know what needs to be done to make it work?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri sorry for the delay and my previous messages. I mis-wrote there. But doing onPause didn't work to stop the audio. :(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should call through to the [WebView's `onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onPause%28%29) and [`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onResume%28%29) from your Activity's `onPause()` and `onResume()`, respectively.

> Pauses any extra processing associated with this WebView and its
>   associated DOM, plugins, JavaScript etc. For example, if this WebView
>   is taken offscreen, this could be called to reduce unnecessary CPU or
>   network traffic. When this WebView is again "active", call onResume().

---

There's also [`pauseTimers()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#pauseTimers%28%29), which affects all of the WebViews within your application:

> Pauses all layout, parsing, and JavaScript timers for all WebViews.
>   This is a global requests, not restricted to just this WebView. This
>   can be useful if the application has been paused.

Comment: Very weird that it does not do this automatically. It seems to be only a problem in Android versions before 4.2. Youtube audio for example keeps playing even if you close your app completely.

Comment: If you call ```webView.pauseTimers()```, it may break adMob ads.

Answer (score 12):

Accepted answer didnt work for me - just using `onPause` in a fragment was not enough to stop music on Android 9. I had to also do:

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    webview?.destroy()

    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this only worked for Android 11 - the audio stops when fragment is destroyed. But how to stop audio when fragment / activity is paused, e.g. when user presses the home button?

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for the Jetpack Compose can be solved by capturing the WebView (https://google.github.io/accompanist/webview/) in `onCreated` and then use it to call `destroy()`.

```
val webViewState = rememberWebViewState(webViewUrl.value)
val webView = remember {
  mutableStateOf<android.webkit.WebView?>(null)
}

//..inside Composable..
WebView(
  state = webViewState,
  captureBackPresses = true,
  onCreated = { wv ->
    webView.value = wv
  }
)

//..on Back Press/Close Button..
webView.value?.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case WebView `onPause()` and `onResume()` is not working for me.

**Solution:**
onPause I load the below URL to stop the audio:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.location=document.location");
```