# How to pause/destroy the webview in android fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, video, android-listview, webview

I have fragment in that contains the list view.In listview loaded with webview's for playing the video's.

playing the video's are success but if video is playing i am moved to another fragment video playing is not stopped.video play's the back ground.

How can i stop/pause/destroy the webview video in android when moving from one fragment to another fragment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop youtube video playing in Android webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview)

Comment: @random i tried this but it is not working for me...please see the your answer below comments...